# Google Chrome Console not displaying correct data after removing array element with splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, console

After doing this:

```
var collection = ['foo', 'bar', 'john'];
console.log(collection);


collection.splice(0,1)
console.log(collection);
```

I get this

[image]

Why does the Chrome console display only two elements instead of all three before the splice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Because variables only hold references to objects and the console doesn't deep-clone when displaying an object.

---

- The `collection` variable *refers* to your `Array`, since `Array`s are `Object`s. In JavaScript, variables only hold *references* to objects.
- When you mutate your `collection` array, the `collection` variable refers/points to the changed array.
- When you click that small arrow icon to expand your array in the console, it reads the logged variable again; which has now changed.

The console doesn't deep-clone an object before displaying it.

Comment: But it changed after the console.log. It’s hard for me to understand how something after can affect something that comes before.

Comment: @RobertRocha Doesn't matter; When you click that arrow icon to expand the Array, you can imagine it does `console.log(collection)` again to display the contents. Makes sense now?

Comment: You see that blue "i" next to the array? It says "value was computed just now". Every time you open that array to see the values, the Dev console checks the value again, to give you the most recent value.

Comment: Thanks @Sidney! Your comment made me understand this better.

Comment: Where can I read more about the meaning of the 'i' I tried googling but I get tons of results.

Comment: You are reading a lot into this. Pressing the arrow to expand the Array in your console reads again the value it originally logged which has by now  changed. There's really nothing more to it. That `i` is just a warning that you are viewing something that was changed.

Answer (score 0):

the result is correct.
splice(x,y) method removes element starting from x index and y specifies number of elements to remove ie; 1 element in your case.
the thing to remember is splice alters your original array.